# Did Mel Gibson give any of his profits back to charity?

Tags: the-passion-of-the-christ, mel-gibson

Did Mel Gibson give any of his profits from *The Passion of the Christ* back to charity?  He raked in a lot of money but I can't find anything on the internet of him sharing his profit.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that he would?

Comment: While Mel Gibson is a movie celebrity, I'm not sure his charitable habits (or lack thereof) are really movie-related.

Comment: I don't really understand the questions relevance anyway.  Where is it stated that he would give a portion of his earnings from that movie to charity?  Was that something he promised when he made the movie?

Comment: I see relevance, by exploiting a theme that is a core part of a world religion that traditionally provides social benefit, the question arouses whether he use the circumstances of the relevance of this topic to gain own profit or having a social awareness that comes with adapting that that surpasses a stalone movie or pornographic depictions.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred - I think that would only apply if Gibson *at least* hinted that he wants to do the Christian thing and donate part of the proceeds.

Comment: Should we ask this question about another multi-millionaire actor next?  Which one?

Comment: I've voted to close. Without some indication that he intended to donate his profits, this fails the "notability" test for me.

Comment: I disagree with the issues with this question. It should be a relatively easy answer. It asks about a movie and a producer. Answer it, or not. Down-vote it, or not. but close it? not sure I agree with that.

Answer (score 6):

**Surprisingly (to me) Mel Gibson actually donates a fair amount of money to charities.**<sup>**[1](http://philanthropynewsdigest.org/news/mel-gibson-donates-10-million-to-los-angeles-hospitals-for-international-charity-care)**, [**2**](https://www.looktothestars.org/celebrity/mel-gibson), [**3**](http://www.hollyscoop.com/mel-gibson/mel-gibson-named-one-of-the-most-generous-stars.html)</sup>

Having said that, it is unclear exactly what portion of his money (from what source) has gone to *which* charity organisation, however:

- [*The Passion of the Christ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ) was released in **2004** and earned a total of US$370,782,930<sup>**[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ#Release)**</sup>
- He has donated to charities from as early as **2004** to as late as **2007**<sup>**[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Gibson#Philanthropy)**</sup>
- Which means that he *could* have donated at least *some* of his earnings to charity after the release of *The Passion of the Christ*.

---

<sup>**1.** http://philanthropynewsdigest.org/news/mel-gibson-donates-10-million-to-los-angeles-hospitals-for-international-charity-care</sup>

**2.** https://www.looktothestars.org/celebrity/mel-gibson

**3.** http://www.hollyscoop.com/mel-gibson/mel-gibson-named-one-of-the-most-generous-stars.html

**4.** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ#Release

**5.** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Gibson#Philanthropy

Comment: Yet, his wife is Catholic.   Listen to Dan Dennett here:  https://youtu.be/EUeQXmYVamA?t=49m15s